# Search Contacts with all Voice Search Commands?

Tags: contacts, voice-command

Is there any way to integrate voice search's navigate to/directions to/map of commands with your contact list? If I want to go to Bob Jones's house, I don't want to go to Bob Jones Co.

Comment: I have this same problem as well.  I am unable to call any of my contacts.  I say "Call Dad" and it dials someone in Daytona.  I presume that if someone answers @drhorrible's question, they will also answer mine.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `navigate to bob jones home`?

You can use the label on the address when using the voice command. The above command is different than `navigate to bob jones work`.

*Update:* One thing to remember: Your contacts need to be accessible to the Google Servers. In other words, you need to be syncing to your Google account. The actual voice-to-text work is done on Google's servers, not on your phone. (Try using voice search while in Airline mode.) See this [Google Support thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=027fcc5de41efbfc&hl=en&start=40).

And, of course, your Contacts need to be in your "Searchable items". (I get there by hitting the search button, then the blue 'g' to the left, then the settings icon.)

Comment: I haven't tried `navigate` but I have tried `call wifes_name mobile` to no avail.

Comment: @Chance: It works for me on my Droid. Does your wife have a common name and it's picking up a different contact?

Comment: @Al Everett, in the case of my wife, it is an unusual spelling, but it seems to still understand it.  Let's say my wife's name is Taresuh.  I say `Call Taresuh` and it does a Google search for `Call Taresuh`, so it obviously picks up the name correctly, it just doesn't have the actual call as an option.

Comment: Furthermore confusing matters, it worked last week.  I was able to say `Call Dan Mobile` last week.  Today, I say `Call Tim Mobile` and it has various options, `Call Tim Wells Mobile Tire Services`, `Call Telecom Italia Mobile S.P.A. - Il Telefonino`.  Here's where it gets strange.  It gives `Call Dan - Mobile` which I think it is picking up from my Voice Search history.

Comment: Voice Search is obviously still a work-in-progress.

Comment: @Al Everett, if you don't mind, could you share what your Search Settings are (i.e search Contacts, Web), at least just the common ones?  Do you have your contacts synced with your google account? Thanks.

Comment: I have everything synced to my Google account. SafeSearch off. Personalized recognition on. Search is on for Web, Apps, Contacts, Voice Search.

Comment: @Al Everett, Thanks.  I think, based on this [link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=027fcc5de41efbfc&hl=en&start=40), that the contacts have to exist in my Google account in order for me to call them.  So, here's the question, is there a way to move my Phone contacts to my Gmail account.  Syncing to my Google Account is only working one way (google to phone).

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head, but that would be a good question for this site (like [this one](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-to-move-phone-contacts-to-google)).

Comment: @Chance: That makes sense, too. When you use the voice search, you're going to Google Servers; it's not happening on the phone.

Comment: @Al Everett, (by the way, can I just say @Al?), that looks to be the case.  I added my wife's name to my Google account online (I haven't tried the exporting via the phone yet), and Voice Search worked.  As much work as you have done in helping me, if you wanted to right a complete answer based on our discussion (I think it should include the links each one of us provided), I would give you the bounty.

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: I haven't investigated all the ways to export people to my Google Account.  However, whenever I view a contact and hit my `Settings` button, it gives me the option to `Join Contact`.  So, if I have their email address from my Google Account, I can join it to that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you speak with a US accent? I'm in Aus and find the voice commands work far better if I try a US accent than my regular Australian drawl.

Answer (score 0):

Voice Search for contacts only works with contact from the primary account setup on the Android phone. Also the primary account contact sync must be enable. I confirmed it by testing with my Galaxy S 4G. Since primary account on an Android phone must be a gmail account, this also means the voice search for contacts only works if the contact is stored in the gmail account.
Since my main email account is with live.com, which I had setup on my Android phone using MS Exchange Sync, I came up with this is work around to allow Voice Search. I go to my Gmail account and add contacts that I like to be able to do voice search with. I made sure the contact only have names entered with no other information. This way, I can enable contact sync with the gmail account to perform voice search without allowing the gmail contact pollute the combined contact list on my Android phone. If you really don't want Gmail account to show up in your phone at all, you can always separate & then delete the gmail account from your other account. As long as the contact sync is enabled, the voice search will still work.
The is kind of a pain, but too bad for me since I only care to add contacts to Gmail for relatively few people that I actually call/text often. It also helps that Gmail web interface was done in a way that is really easy to add contacts with just names.