# How do I import all contacts from a SIM-card to an Android phone?

Tags: contacts, htc-sense, htc-wildfire, sim-card

My mother have got a HTC Wildfire with Android 2.2.

Now I want to import all contacts from her old SIM-card to the phone. I did it and it worked. Then I switched to the new SIM-card, and now when I start the phone, the contacts has disappeared.

How can I import the contacts from the old SIM-card to the Android phone? This is a really annoying problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/637/2422

Comment: @Daniel: I do **not** want to transfer my contacts to Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a pre-installed app on the HTC Wildfire [**Transfer Data**](http://www.htc.com/www/howto.aspx?id=3505&type=1&p_id=316) that transferred all contacts and SMS from the old SonyEricsson phone, it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

Two questions:

1. Are you sure the SIM contacts were really imported or only displayed.
2. Is the option to show phone contacts checked after you changed the SIM.

If you go to Contacts, press Menu -> Import/Export -> Import from SIM card.

The SIM contacts should be imported into the phone and remain there. It is then just a matter of getting phone contacts displayed.

Comment: I did exactly this `Menu > Import/Export > Import from SIM card` and it worked. But all contacts were cleared when I switched to the new SIM card.

Comment: An additional hint: if you have swapped the SIM cards around while the phone was still switched on, the contacts app will show SIM contacts from whatever SIM was in the phone when the it was restarted, but there will be no "import from SIM card" option on the menu. You'll need to reboot to get this option back.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Contacts. You can reach this from the contacts shortcut in your app drawer or home screen, or via the contacts tab in your phone dialer.
2. Press the Menu button.
3. Select Import/Export.
4. Select Export from SIM.
5. Click Select All, or manually tick each contact you wish to copy to the phone.
6. You may be asked where to copy the contacts to; select the appropriate option.

It takes no more than a second or two to copy over a few hundred contacts, so you'll be done in less than the time it takes to send yourself just one via SMS.

Answer (score 0):

If like most people you use a Google account on your android phone, import your contacts to your google account, then they will be on any future android phone as soon as you sign in.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all your SIM contacts to HTC Wildfire S. Import them as phone contacts, Google contacts, or Exchange ActiveSync contacts, if you have set up the relevant accounts.
From the Home screen, tap  > People.
On the All tab, press , and then tap Import/Export > Import from SIM card.
If you have Google or Exchange ActiveSync accounts set up on HTC Wildfire S, tap the type for the imported contacts.
Do one of the following:
Tap one or more SIM contacts you want to import.
To import all contacts, press , and then tap Select all.
Tap Save.

Comment: 1) Isn't this the same as [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/45117/16575) describes? 2) OP referred to the "original Wildfire" (no "S") ;)