# Transfer all Contacts in Phone and Sim to Google Contacts

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account, samsung-galaxy-y

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move phone contacts to Google?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-to-move-phone-contacts-to-google)

I am using my New Samsung Galaxy Y mobile phone.
In My Contacts, I see that some are in SIM Memory, Some are in Phone Memory while others are in Google Accounts.
In the Import/Export Option, I see Import/Export to SD card and Import/Export to SIM Card.

I want to copy all my contacts in phone and sim memory to my Google Account. How do I do that? Is there any way to do it rather than doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer given by [Niall C.](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/98/niall-c) in [How to move phone contacts to Google?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-to-move-phone-contacts-to-google)

This is the simplest way that I found to do it with my Samsung Galaxy S:

From the main Contacts screen, hit Menu, then More, then Import/Export, then Export to SD card.
Connect the phone to the PC and mount the phone's SD card as a removable drive.
Open browser to GMail, select Contacts then Import. Select the file on the phone's SD card, then Import.
Voila! On the next sync, they're back as my phone as Google contacts.

Answer (score 1):

In the Contacts Menu there should be an option called Merge with Google.

Comment: After spending a lot of time, looking around, I did not find any such option anywhere.

Comment: Couldn't find that either, what make/model do you have? Could you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: (latest april 2019) You can do this using the new Google Contacts app. It has an option to migrate all SIM/Phone contacts to Gmail.